# How to track player money change in SourceMod?

Tags: scripting, game-development, steam

I'm writing a plugin for CSGO and I want to track changes in players' money. I tried to use the following:

```php
new Cash = GetEntProp(client, Prop_Send, "m_iAccount");
```

But it issues money before the change. How is it possible to receive the player's money exactly after their change?